# How do I print the random outcome of an entry input in a list?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7

**Code**

```
list = [ee1.get(), ee2.get(), ee3.get(), ee4.get(), ee5.get(), ee6.get(), ee7.get(), ee8.get(), ee9.get(), ee10.get()]
context = "What does", random.choice(list),"mean?"
labelquestion = Label(window, text = context, font = "Serif 10 bold")
```

**Question**

When I run this, it outputs `"{What does} {} mean?"`

How can I fix this so that it outputs `"What does"-random entry from list-"this mean?"`
(The things in the list are entries)

Comment: It looks like it's what this code is doing... Can you post some kind of a [mre]? Also, try to avoid naming variables like built-in names, like `list`

Comment: It looks like the ee it is randomly pulling is a blank object . Are you sure .get() returns a string that you want?

Comment: It is because `context` is a tuple.  Use `context = f'What does "{random.choice(list)}" mean?'` instead.  BTW, don't use keyword (`list`) as variable name.

Comment: @acw1668 I have done what you said and it has improved it, but now it prints `"What does "" mean?"` It does not print the input of the entry.

Comment: Please show how/when this code runs. If it's not showing the data, it's probably running before the user has had a chance to enter anything.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley It runs when the entry boxes have been filled with an input and they have clicked a button saying Submit on it.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What you say doesn't agree with the code you posted. If the code is running after the user enters data, then the `.get()` methods should work and the values should be there.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley The entries are from a previous GUI, and I am attempting to put the info from the first GUI onto the second. I think that it’s not outputting correctly because I can’t grab info from previous GUIs - is this correct? If so, is there a way I can fix it?

Comment: You need to give us a proper example that reproduces your problem. The code you posted doesn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example based on your code and information in the comment:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import random

window = tk.Tk()

ee1 = tk.Entry(window)
ee1.grid(row=0, column=0)

ee2 = tk.Entry(window)
ee2.grid(row=0, column=1)

ee3 = tk.Entry(window)
ee3.grid(row=0, column=2)

ee4 = tk.Entry(window)
ee4.grid(row=0, column=3)

ee5 = tk.Entry(window)
ee5.grid(row=0, column=4)

ee6 = tk.Entry(window)
ee6.grid(row=1, column=0)

ee7 = tk.Entry(window)
ee7.grid(row=1, column=1)

ee8 = tk.Entry(window)
ee8.grid(row=1, column=2)

ee9 = tk.Entry(window)
ee9.grid(row=1, column=3)

ee10 = tk.Entry(window)
ee10.grid(row=1, column=4)

def submit():
    words = [ee1.get(), ee2.get(), ee3.get(), ee4.get(), ee5.get(), 
             ee6.get(), ee7.get(), ee8.get(), ee9.get(), ee10.get()]
    context = f"What does '{random.choice(words)}' mean?"
    labelquestion.config(text=context)

tk.Button(window, text="Submit", command=submit).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='w')

labelquestion = tk.Label(window, font="Serif 10 bold")
labelquestion.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=4)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Would be nicer with a function that takes row and column as args then looping for rows and cols + fill a list instead of 10 vars, or not? :)

Comment: @Ruli I just want to simulate OP code to show that if those entries have something input and then a button is clicked to trigger a function, `context` should not show empty string from `random.choice()`.